# MySql Timezone JDBC issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timezone

I am trying to insert a date value in MySql table name person and column name regdate with data type = datetime. I am setting a value e.g. '2019-08-21 20:25:20' but after saving +5:30 hours get added and value which gets stored is '2019-08-22 03:55:20'. Generating the date value using below Java code

```
Timestamp curDate = Timestamp.valueOf(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toLocalDateTime());
```

and then using `.setTimestamp(1, curdate);` in INSERT query.

I have checked that the timezone of MySql is set to IST (GMT+0530). App Server timezone is also set to IST. But I am not able to understand why +5:30 hours are getting added even if I explictly setting the date value.

I have tried setting timezone in connection string as `?serverTimezone=Asia/Kolkata` but didn't work.

But if I run the same code using my local machine connecting same MySql instance, I get no problem and same value gets stored without addition of 5:30 hours. I checked App Server timezone and it is IST.

MySql version - 5.7.17-log
mysql-connector-java - 8.0.15

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

First of all, you are mixing the terrible legacy date-time classes (`java.sql.Timestamp`) with the modern *java.time* classes. Don’t. Use only classes from the *java.time* packages.

## `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

You are using `LocalDateTime` to track a moment, which it cannot. By definition, that class does *not* represent a point on the time line. That class has a date and a time-of-day but intentionally lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Calling `toLocalDateTime` strips away vital information about zone/offset.

## Tools lie

You are likely getting confused by the well-intentioned but unfortunate behavior of many tools to dynamically apply a time zone while generating text to represent the date-time value retrieved from the database. You can avoid this by using Java & JDBC to get the pure unadulterated value from the database.

## `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

You failed to disclose the exact data type of your column in your database. If you are trying to track a moment, use a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In MySQL 8 that would, apparently, be the `TIMESTAMP` type according to [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html). (I am a Postgres guy, not a MySQL user.)

In JDBC 4.2 and later, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. So no need to over touch `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

Unfortunately, the JDBC spec oddly chose to not require support for `Instant` (a moment in UTC`) nor for`ZonedDateTime`(a moment as seen in some particular time zone). The spec does require support for [`OffsetDateTime`][2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Tip: Learn to work in UTC for the most part. Adjust into a time zone only when required by business logic or for presentation to the user.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Write to the database via a prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

View that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of some particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

Comment: Specifically w.r.t. MySQL, be aware that **(1)** As noted in the cited MySQL documentation, "TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC." **(2)** MySQL Connector/J still has some kinks [like this one](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444) to work out regarding `java.time.*`.